# What could be the reason for lxml.etree.relaxng to return DocumentInvalid without logging an error?

Tags: python, lxml

I have code as follows:

```
try:
    schema = lxml.etree.RelaxNG(file=schema_file)
    schema.assertValid(etree)
except lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid as exception:
    print(schema.error_log)
    print(exception.error_log)
    raise exception
```

It consistently raises a DocumentInvalid error:

```
DocumentInvalid: Document does not comply with schema
```

yet prints no errors in either the schema error log or the global error log.

This only happens for some files, others validate correctly, or give a reason for failing to validate.  (It's a very long schema, so I won't quote it here.)

I don't even know where to start looking. What could the cause possibly be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how you can get an error message

```
try:
    schema = lxml.etree.RelaxNG(file=schema_file)
    schema.assertValid(etree)
except lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid as exception:
    print(exception.error_log.filter_from_errors()[0])
    raise exception
```